# Instant rails 2.0 doesn't start the server in windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have use the instant rails. In ruby console window I have created a new ruby rails application but I can't run the file server from the script folder.
To run it i used script/server command. it says "server" is not recognized internal or external command.
I am not running windows as administration

Comment: What version of Rails does Instant Rails 2.0 install?  what does 'rails -v' tell you

Comment: Ruby Installer for Windows
  Ruby Version 1.8.6
Installer Version 186-26

Comment: Iam new in Ruby , I tried google to solve this problem can't found solution

Comment: Just FYI, rails developers rarely use windows for their development environment. If I were you, I would try using Ubuntu.

Comment: I think your are still OK developing on Windows,  you just can't useInstant Rails to set up your development environment.  check out http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby-on-rails/running-rails-3-on-windows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't know what your environment looks like but it looks like instant rails isn't maintained anymore (discontinued in 2007).

That being said it might be that you're not running the script using a Ruby executable.

I would personally suggest switching to [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) or [RubyStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack).